# Replacing Hotlinked images with Low Resolution versions

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, hotlinking

i am working on website of a Digital Gadgets Manufacturer.
Product images are hotlinked from hundreds of blogs & forums. which is causing bandwidth issues.

we want to replace all hotlinked images with their low resolution versions, using
.htaccess

means if the hotlinked image path is

```
http://www.example.com/products/gadget123/gadget123.png
```

we want to redirect it to

```
http://www.example.com/images/low-res/gadget123.png
```

hotlinked image paths are different, means they may be from sub-directory of any directory.

for example

```
/images/products/abc/gadget_abc200.jpg
/products/images/abc/gadgetabc5155_packing.png
/downloads/brochures/abc2012/abc2012_user_guide.jpg

etc...
```

but all low resolution images will be in

```
http://www.example.com/images/low-res/
```

directory, and their names will be same as their high resolution versions.

Answer (score 0):

I am making the assumption that the filename is always the same between the high and low resolution images regardless of the original folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond expr "! %{HTTP_REFERER} -strmatch '*://%{HTTP_HOST}/*'"
RewriteRule ^(images|products|downloads)/[a-zA-z0-9]+/([a-zA-z0-9]+)(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)$ images/low-res/$2$3
```

This will at least work for the example provided. If there are additional subfolders that need to be taken into account the rule would need to be adapted accordingly.

Comment: What happens when you try this?